# Liouville superoperators of multi-qubit quantum channels : Need for Numerics

Tags: quantum-operation

As greatly described [here](https://forest-benchmarking.readthedocs.io/en/latest/superoperator_representations.html), a density matrix can be vectorized in column-major order such that a (unitary) channel can be written

$$
\rho \rightarrow |\rho\rangle = vec(\rho) \\
\rho' = U \rho U^{\dagger} \rightarrow \mathcal{U} = U^*\otimes U \\
|\rho'\rangle = \mathcal{U} |\rho\rangle \leftrightarrow  \rho' = unvec(|\rho'\rangle)
$$

Is there a simple way to represent the multi-qubit Liouville superoperators using its constituents? Say,we have single qubit $U = X \otimes I$, and the $\mathcal{U} = X^*\otimes X$,

$$
\mathcal{\tilde{U}}_2 = U^*\otimes U = X \otimes I \otimes X \otimes I
$$

Is there a way of writing $\mathcal{\tilde{U}}_2$ in terms of the single qubit superoperator $\mathcal{U}$ and identities? Numerically, if it is possible, I assume there needs to be a ton of reshaping and index shuffling is involved.

Comment: You only need a permutation of the tensor factors $X\otimes I \otimes X \otimes I \simeq X\otimes X \otimes I \otimes I = \mathcal{U} \otimes \mathcal{I}$